# Checkmate in 6 moves

Tags: checkmate, problems

Can somebody tell me the right six moves, and what has to be done? This puzzle was created vy 
Fritz Giegold and published in Zeit-Magazin in 1976

```
[FEN "n1N3br/2p1Bpkr/1pP2R1b/pP1p1PpR/Pp4P1/1P6/1K1P4/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Why do you think it is mate in 6?

Comment: Is the position even reachable by a series of legal moves? Perhaps this is a retrograde problem.

Comment: I bet the first move of the solution is `bxa6 e.p' .

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen Genius! A genuine LOL. So I guess the second point of the puzzle (and I am even more hopeless at retrograde than regular) is to prove that the last black move was a5

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen You got it. I didn't notice the pawn structure, you're right.

Comment: I have a strange feeling this may be a composed problem presented in the Chessmaster program under 'John Nunn's puzzles', but I'm unable to check right now.

Comment: Even after bxa6 e.p. (if we can prove it's legal), it seems to be a mate in seven, not six.

Comment: Yes, I can't count. Jon (answer below) is correct - there is a forced mate in 6 but Jon I believe hasn't enough reputation to merely comment rather than answer. He's from the same club as I so he's told me the solution - I'll leave it before I post to see if others can find it, it's quite fun, and Jon's hint is quite good.

Comment: @IanBush This site is question-answer, not solving puzzles.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution:

> 1.Rh1 d4 2.Ra1 d3 3.Ra3 bxa3+ 4.Ka1 a2 5.Ba3 Kxf6 6.Bb2#

It can also be [found](https://www.yacpdb.org/#66738) in the YACPBD chess problem database.

Comment: FYI- Puzzle 17 in the Nunn's Puzzles section of the Chessmaster tutorial.